# win32com excel missing workbooks attribute

Tags: python, excel, win32com

On my computer I made

```
import win32com.client
xl = win32com.client.DispacthEx("Excel.Application")
xl
```

and I get

```
<COMObject Excel.Application>
```

When I do

```
wb =  xl.workbooks()
```

everything is fine.

But then on another computer I did the same thing and I get

[image: picture of odd excel]

It's this object library with no workbooks attribute, but to be fair I used
xl.workbooks.  Could it be case sensitive?  On the first computer it wasn't case sensitive, so it's really a mystery.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  win32com is selectively case sensitive depending on whether it's early or late binding.  There's some gobbledygook on this that I don't understand, but this is what I understand.  If there's an AttributeError on win32com, it's because the case is wrong.  To find the right case, or to find objects that you're allowed to use for this item, go here.  It maybe works, because it curiously has vba in the url, but it worked for me:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/excel/object-model

You might be wondering why one computer is case insensitive and the other is case sensitive.  If it were that easy, why would Microsoft pay up to recruit budding software engineers from Harvey Mudd?